# Java generating "random" numbers that don't repeat for 2^48 period

Tags: java, random

Basically I want to generate random numbers that won't ever repeat for a very long period (I don't want to use a sequence) like for example the LCG that java uses:

```
 synchronized protected int next(int bits) {
       seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
       return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits));
 }
```

As I understand the seed in this case will only repeat after 2^48 calls to next is this correct?

so it is my understand that if I did a method like:

```
 synchronized protected long next() {
       seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
       return seed;
 }
```

The seed value is guaranteed not to repeat before 2^48 calls?

Comment: what if I removed the shift wouldn't it be then a guaranteed 2^64 period?

Comment: No, this is not correct. The shift by 48 does not inherently have anything to do with the [guaranteed] period length. Wikipedia lists [the properties required](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length) for a full-length LCG. The numbers are very particularly chosen -- and I am not sure what period guarantee the above variant uses. See Mikola's answer for a suitable alternative.

Comment: Yes according to wikipedia the numbers in java.util.Random guarantee a full length.

Comment: Indeed, that LCG *should* be full-cycle (Wikipedia doesn't say this, it just says that the numbers were chosen ;-) ... but the numbers hold with the properties listed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not for that LCG, since you are modding out by 2^48 each time you call it (and thus the period/state is at most 2^48 in length).  If you want a better random number generator, you could try the Mersenne twister:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

The standard MT19937 has a period of 2^19937-1 (!!!)  That should be more than you will ever need.

Comment: Event MT800 has a sufficiently large period (2^800-1 ... interestingly how they are fittingly named ;-)

Comment: So for the LCG above it would in fact not repeat for 2^48 right?, since the m, a and c values in that algorithm are chosen for the maximum period.

Answer (score 10):

For reference, the parameters for the [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) implemented in [`java.util.Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) are as follows:

*a* = 25214903917 = 7 x 443 x 739 x 11003
*c* = 11
*m* = 2<sup>48</sup>
*a* – 1 = 25214903916

The [period length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length) is at most *m* if and only if *all* of the following are true:

1. ✔ *c* and *m* and  are [relatively prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime)
2. ✔ *a* – 1 is divisible by all prime factors of *m*
3. ✔ *a* – 1 is a multiple of 4 if *m* is a multiple of 4

Yes, the period is 2<sup>48</sup>. The problem is "that the low order bits go through very short cycles." The strong correlation between the low order bits of successive values significantly limits what you can do with them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SecureRandom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) as a drop in replacement from random. It doesn't repeat as quickly as Random does.

Comment: But since SecureRandom is non-deterministic while the probability of the seed repeating before 2^48 using Random is 0, wouldn't it be something > 0 for SecureRandom?. The thing is I don't really care about the randomness but more about the numbers not repeating for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collection.shuffle()` for that might be Performance issue..

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) 
            number.add(i);
        Collections.shuffle(number);
```