# When will the sequence of numbers produced by Random.nextInt() repeat

Tags: java, random

Does anyone know if the Java's `Random.nextInt()` will ever repeat itself after sometime?

Concretely, is there such a number `n` such that the following two lists are equal?

```
List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> b = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   a.add(randObject.nextInt());

for (int i = n; i <= n * 2 ; ++i)
   b.add(randObject.nextInt());
```

Is it guaranteed that every random object has a period?
(Note: Objects of different seeds don't have to have the same period)

Comment: The period of `j.u.Random` is at most 2^48. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6463893/139010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the Java's Random.nextInt() will ever repeat itself after sometime?

Yes it will. Since the generator has a finite amount of state, the generated sequence has a finite period.

> Concretely, what is the number n such that the following two lists are equal?

That's not specified and depends on the Java implementation.

> Is it guaranteed that there will always be such n for each Random object, regardless of what its seed is?

The period is finite. However, it's not necessarily the case that it's the same for every seed.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask if every seed has the same period, what I meant was , "Does every seed has a period?"

Comment: @OneTwoThree yes, because `j.u.Random` is a pseudorandom generator (implemented as an LCG).

Comment: "Does every seed has a period?" **yes**

Answer (score -1):

If you are *really really really* lucky enough, yes. Otherwise no.

But from the *javadoc*

> The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.